# How to filter post content and force every link (<a>) made in blocks to return urldecode(<a>) with readable value?

Tags: filters, urls, content, post-content

Will really appreciate your help with something.

I'm using non English letters in my URL slugs. So every time I add an internal or external link with non English letters to my post (via blocks editor in WP) it becomes `mysite.com/%d7%#t^%....` and so on.

I would like a function or something to add to my functions.php that will filter every post content, find all links `<a>` (internal or external ones) and will apply `urldecode()` to each link found in the content to fix the link to a readable format in the dev tools.

Thanks ahead.